# AWS CodeDeploy-Agenten on Ubuntu 20.0LTS, Ruby errors

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, ubuntu-20.04

I've got some errors, while trying to install the AWS code-deploy agent via :

```
wget https://bucket-name.s3.region-identifier.amazonaws.com/latest/install

./install auto
```

I know the AWS documentation said 16.04 or 18.04. But wondering if I am the first who tried it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    8: from ./install:33:in `<main>'
    7: from ./install:33:in `new'
    6: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/logger.rb:389:in `initialize'
    5: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/logger.rb:389:in `new'
    4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/logger/log_device.rb:18:in `initialize'
    3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/logger/log_device.rb:83:in `set_dev'
    2: from ./install:21:in `method_missing'
    1: from ./install:21:in `map'
./install:22:in `block in method_missing': undefined method `path' for #<IO:<STDOUT>> (NoMethodError)
```

Would be nice if some one have a tip.

best and thx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently CodeDeploy is not yet compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 since the latter comes with ruby 2.7 while CodeDeploy supports max 2.5. There is a solution [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/239#issuecomment-622630774) which repacks the deb package to force the check to pass:

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get install -y ruby
wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/codedeploy-agent_1.0-1.1597_all.deb
mkdir codedeploy-agent_1.0-1.1597_ubuntu20
dpkg-deb -R codedeploy-agent_1.0-1.1597_all.deb codedeploy-agent_1.0-1.1597_ubuntu20
sed 's/2.0/2.7/' -i ./codedeploy-agent_1.0-1.1597_ubuntu20/DEBIAN/control
dpkg-deb -b codedeploy-agent_1.0-1.1597_ubuntu20
dpkg -i codedeploy-agent_1.0-1.1597_ubuntu20.deb
systemctl start codedeploy-agent
systemctl enable codedeploy-agent
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. Was struggling for lot of time, and the funny part is no proper error message is given anywehere in logs.

Comment: There is same solution here https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/239

Answer (score 5):

**Not sure about 20.04 but I do have a fix for 22.04 in case someone needs. Here it is,**

Installing Code deploy agent on ubuntu 22.04 EC2 Instance

Source:- Github discussions

```
!/bin/bash

# This installs the CodeDeploy agent and its prerequisites on Ubuntu 22.04.

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ruby-full ruby-webrick wget -y

cd /tmp

wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/releases/codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_all.deb

mkdir codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22

dpkg-deb -R codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_all.deb codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22

sed 's/Depends:.*/Depends:ruby3.0/' -i ./codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22/DEBIAN/control

dpkg-deb -b codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22/

sudo dpkg -i codedeploy-agent_1.3.2-1902_ubuntu22.deb

systemctl list-units --type=service | grep codedeploy

sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

Answer (score 4):

To install the latest version of the CodeDeploy agent on Ubuntu 20.04:

sudo ./install auto > /tmp/logfile

Note: Writing the output to a temporary log file is a workaround that should be used while AWS address a known bug with the install script on Ubuntu 20.04.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-ubuntu.html

Comment: just a note for anyone who hunts for this solution - this no longer works